# Parse string as DateTimeOffset in Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, datetimeoffset

Hey, I am trying to create an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` in which a string property is converted/cast to a DateTimeOffset so that DateTimeOffset operations can be performed on it.

We are using Linq2SQL as our data provider, which does support converting strings to the SQL equivalent of DateTimeOffset. Ideally I want the expression to be evaluated directly inside  the IQueryable data source, and not in memory as an IEnumerable.

See below for an example of what I have tried to far:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyValue;
}

Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> filter = mc => DateTimeOffset.Parse(mc.MyValue) > new DateTimeOffset(2007,1,1);
```

Unfortunately this definition of filter causes an in memory evaluation.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the physical table column a `char` or a `datetime`?

Comment: In SQL, the column is a string (nvarchar I believe)

Answer (score 1):

Since the underlying physical table column is `nvarchar` not `datetime`, I think you are out of luck. The LINQ2SQL provider knows that it is `nvarchar` data, and therefore will not generate native SQL expressions that deal with it as a `datetime` value.

To be honest, I can't even see a safe way of doing this with raw hand-crafted `SqlCommand` objects. You really ought to read the data into memory as `String`, then convert it to `DateTimeOffset`, then manually filter it in memory. If you want native SQL filtering on this column, you need to change the table schema.